# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl cannot be cast

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте, выскакивает эта ошибка, не пойму почему.

```
public Country getCountry(int id) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Country country = (Country) session.get(Country.class, id);
    return country;
}
```

вот Контроллер которым вызываю

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCountry/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public Country getCountryById(@PathVariable int id) {
    return countryService.getCountry(id);
}
```

Помогите понять в чем проблема.
Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl cannot be cast to org.arpit.java2blog.model.Country
    at org.arpit.java2blog.dao.CountryDAO.getCountry(CountryDAO.java:32)
    at org.arpit.java2blog.service.CountryService.getCountry(CountryService.java:23)
    at org.arpit.java2blog.service.CountryService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cc30a22.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at org.arpit.java2blog.service.CountryService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$faa92f2c.getCountry(<generated>)
    at org.arpit.java2blog.controller.CountryController.getCountryById(CountryController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn clean install` в корне проекта решило проблему.